# Why is there reduction in Turnaround time in higher CPU config, but no change in CPU utilization?

Tags: python, machine-learning, kubernetes, optimization, cpu

I am running a kubernetes cluster to expose a flask service that runs a Yolov3 model.

If the pod configuration is `2 cpu`, it runs much faster (~1.5sec) compared to `700m cpu`, which takes ~3.5 seconds.

The strange thing is there is no change in CPU utilization.

I am attaching the graph where the scale up of CPU happened with no change in utlization.

It is not a yolo thing, because the same thing is happening in other frameworks like pytorch as well.

Any ideas on how to proceed further will be helpful. I can modify the question as per what other details are required.

[image]